# How can I power a 5V USB device from a power bank and a solar panel in parallel?

Tags: power-supply, usb, solar-cell

I have a [Panasonic BQ-CC87ABBA eneloop Battery Charger](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07WVVXQX7) that only seems to function properly with at least ~1A of current.  I'd like to power it primarily using my [20W X-DRAGON Monocrystalline Portable Solar Panel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00NGKPX4Y), but that isn't working very well with any less than clear direct sun.  If a cloud comes by, the charger lights will blink like it's constantly restarting.

I also have a [Ledlenser Flex3 Powerbank](https://www.ledlenserusa.com/collections/powerbanks/products/flex3), but it doesn't have enough power to completely charge the batteries before its depleted, and it seems like an inefficient pain to serially charge the power bank from solar to then charge other batteries from the power bank.

I was thinking I could solve that problem by using a [USB Y power cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0047AALW6), like the ones that used to be common with external hard drives when a single port could not power the drive.  I'd plug one port of the Y into the solar cell, the other into the power bank, and the micro USB port into the charger.  The hope would be that the two power sources could completely charge the batteries and the power bank would make success less weather dependent.

However, I'd rather not wreck my stuff with a hair-brained idea, so:

1. Are there any issues from sourcing USB power from two independent source like this?  With a simple Y-cable, could one device feed back into the other in some damaging way?
2. Is there any way to make something like this work, or work better? Like by using a more complicated circuit than a simple Y cable?

I've read some other questions, which make me think there might be some issues, but I'm not sure if those really apply to my scenario.  Most of this questions are trying to pull more current than either device is capable of by itself, but I'm not.  I just want to combine two sources to get a steady 1A for a longer period of time.

Comment: What you suggest is likely to damage the solar charger, the battery bank, or both. Those Y cables are not allowed by the USB standard for a reason. That said, given that the draw is less than the maximum of either device, you can use an appropriate power path controller to automatically switch power supplies. Or just diodes, but that way you wouldn't be able to preferentially use solar when possible; it'll just use whichever has a higher voltage.